# Filling in parametric plot

Tags: plotting, color, filling

Writing:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

I get an error instead of:

[image]

How can I correct? Thank you!

Comment: You could do something along those lines `ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, x^2}, Axes -> False]`, in your case `{y, 0, 1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Filling` is not an option for `ParametricPlot`. You can use, instead,

```
ParametricPlot[t {x, 0} + (1 - t) {x, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Axes -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, {1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{1}, {0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, BoundaryStyle -> None,  PlotStyle -> LightBlue]
```

> same picture

Comment: @TeM,  please see the new version.

Comment: @TeM, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.