# Filling in curves in a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I am trying to fill in the area between curves in a parametric plot. I have:

```
ffA[x_, n_] := MathieuCharacteristicA[n, x]; 
ffB[x_, n_] := MathieuCharacteristicB[n, x];

MathieuPlot =ParametricPlot[{{ffA[x, 1], x}, {ffB[x, 1], x}, {ffA[x, 2], x}, 
{ffB[x, 2], x}, {ffA[x, 3], x}, {ffB[x, 3], x}, {ffA[x, 4], x}, {ffB[x, 4], x}}, 
{x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}, 
PlotStyle -> Black, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

I saw the solutions to these questions: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165834/filling-in-parametric-plot), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31659/filling-between-parametric-plots),[3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/filling-between-curves). However, `Filling` only works for `Plot`, and solutions 1/2 don't fill in the area between the curves. According to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64142/filling-between-parametricplot-and-plot), I can shade the area between curves with:

```
coords = Cases[Normal[MathieuPlot], {dir___, Line[x_]} :> x, Infinity];
Graphics[{{{{{Red, Thick, Line@#, Blue, Line@#2, LightBlue, 
        Polygon[Join[#, Reverse@#2]]} & @@ 
      coords}, {Red, Thick, Line@#3, Blue, Line@#4, LightBlue, 
       Polygon[Join[#3, Reverse@#4]]} & @@ 
     coords}, {Red, Thick, Line@#5, Blue, Line@#6, LightBlue, 
      Polygon[Join[#5, Reverse@#6]]} & @@ 
    coords}, {Red, Thick, Line@#7, Blue, Line@#8, LightBlue, 
     Polygon[Join[#7, Reverse@#8]]} & @@ coords}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Ticks -> {True, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to only plot the curves to the right of zero. I suspect that it has something to do with how `coords` is defined, but I am not sure how to modify it. I am also unsure how to make the plots touch the horizontal and vertical axes, similar to the top picture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** You can use a single `ParametricPlot` with the options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to get the same result:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{ffA[x, #] v + (1 - v) ffB[x, #], x} & /@ Range[4]], 
 {x, -10, 10}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Frame -> False, 
 Ticks -> False, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[1, Black], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use a two-parameter `ParametricPlot` and combine the output with your `MathieuPlot` using `Show`:

```
Show[MathieuPlot, 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{ffA[x, #] v + (1 - v) ffB[x, #], x} & /@ Range[4]],
   {x, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Use `PlotRange -> All` and `PlotRangePadding -> None` in the first plot and `{x, -10, 10}` in both plots to get

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering! Thanks!

Do you know if there is a way for the vertical axis to end at the same height as the plot?

Comment: @user85503, try `PlotRangePadding->None` (in `Show` or in `ParametricPlot` that generates `MathieuPlot`.)